# jade script tags are rendering html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, mean-stack

I have an express app using jade templates with a file `views/index.jade`:

```
extends layout

block body
    div
        h2 My Blog
    ul
        li
            a(href='/') Home
        li
            a(href='/addPost') Add a new post

    div(ng-view)

    script(src='js/lib/angular/angular.js')
    script(src='js/app.js')
    script(src='js/services.js')
    script(src='js/controllers.js')
    script(src='js/filters.js')
    script(src='js/directives.js')
```

The html renders fine in the browser, but when I look to examine the javascript files it's all html!

Why is jade rendering html for my javascript files?

[image: js files filled with html]

Comment: What kind of content is in the body of that angular.js html page? My guess is the static file serving might not be configured correctly and when express handles a request for 'js/angular.js' it's handled by one of your routes app.route("*") or something..

Answer (score 0):

woops, I had changed

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

to

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/public'));
```

when it should have been:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Thanks @karolis